# Drush migration argument for xml source

Tags: 7, drush, migrations

I asked [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/234120/is-it-possible-to-include-extra-arguments-when-migrating-via-command-line/249982) question a while back and it was answered correctly and helpfully.

However, I'm currently looking for a different solution.

I need a way to create a custom argument which I can use to specify a different xml document source, like in the following:

```
drush mi migration_test --xml=test.xml
```

Can anyone advice how I can create the custom **--xml** argument ?

Comment: Try to take a look here, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199550/how-to-overridden-command-via-hook-drush-command-alter

Comment: I am also trying to figure out how to do this, and, unless I'm confused, I don't think modifying a drush command is what I'm trying to do. I want to add custom arguments to `drush mim` that I can check for and react to inside my custom migration plugins.